# How to vertically align text in table cell?

Tags: tables, bibtex, vertical-alignment

Here is the latex code to create a table in BibTxtMng

```
 \begin{table}[!htbp]
 \centering
 \caption{Spanish Traffic Sign according to the color and shape \cite{Paper12}}
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}p{3.1cm}|>{\raggedright}p{3.1cm}|>
   {\raggedright}p{3.1cm}|}
   \hline
   Color          & Shape    & Meaning \tabularnewline
   \hline
    Red Rim        & Circle   & Prohibition\tabularnewline
    \hline
    Red Rim (Up)   & Triangle & Danger      \tabularnewline
    \hline
     Red Rim (Down) & Triangle & Yield       \tabularnewline
    \hline
        Red            & Octagonal & Stop\tabularnewline
    \hline
      Blue  & Square &  Recommendation \tabularnewline
       \hline
      Blue &    Circle &    Obligation \tabularnewline
     \hline
     White  & Circle    & End of Prohibition \tabularnewline
     \hline
    Yellow & Circle & End of Prohibition (construction)\tabularnewline
      \hline
       \end{tabular}
       \label{Spanish_TS}
       \end{table}
```

Here is the output table I got

[image]

I want that yellow and circle text (in the last row) being located in the centre of vertical. Not tin the top like that..

How to do it??

Answer (score 5):

You can use `m` column specifier for the last cell in last row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}             %% you need this
\begin{document}
   \begin{table}[!htbp]
 \centering
 \caption{Spanish Traffic Sign according to the color and shape \cite{Paper12}}
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}p{3.1cm}|>{\raggedright}p{3.1cm}|>
   {\raggedright}p{3.1cm}|}
   \hline
   Color          & Shape    & Meaning \tabularnewline
   \hline
    Red Rim        & Circle   & Prohibition\tabularnewline
    \hline
    Red Rim (Up)   & Triangle & Danger      \tabularnewline
    \hline
     Red Rim (Down) & Triangle & Yield       \tabularnewline
    \hline
        Red            & Octagonal & Stop\tabularnewline
    \hline
      Blue  & Square &  Recommendation \tabularnewline
       \hline
      Blue &    Circle &    Obligation \tabularnewline
     \hline
     White  & Circle    & End of Prohibition \tabularnewline
     \hline
    Yellow & Circle & \multicolumn{1}{|m{3.1cm}|}{End of Prohibition (construction)}\tabularnewline
      \hline
       \end{tabular}
       \label{Spanish_TS}
       \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You may use the `m` column specifier for all columns if you have variable width text in them to have vertical alignment.

Comment: Or even in all columns.

Comment: @egreg probably yes, to be on the safer side. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to manually do the linebreaks within a row yourself, you can use a `\Centerstack`, as shown here.  In that case though, the `p` columns are not really needed, unless you want them for their width.  You can dispense with them by deleting that declaration and uncommenting the 3 other lines in my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
%\edef\tmp{\the\baselineskip}
%\setstackgap{L}{\tmp}
\begin{document}
   \begin{table}[!htbp]
 \centering
 \caption{Spanish Traffic Sign according to the color and shape \cite{Paper12}}
%\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
  \begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright}p{3.1cm}|>{\raggedright}p{3.1cm}|>{\raggedright}p{3.1cm}|}
   \hline
   Color          & Shape    & Meaning \tabularnewline
   \hline
    Red Rim        & Circle   & Prohibition\tabularnewline
    \hline
    Red Rim (Up)   & Triangle & Danger      \tabularnewline
    \hline
     Red Rim (Down) & Triangle & Yield       \tabularnewline
    \hline
        Red            & Octagonal & Stop\tabularnewline
    \hline
      Blue  & Square &  Recommendation \tabularnewline
       \hline
      Blue &    Circle &    Obligation \tabularnewline
     \hline
     White  & Circle    & End of Prohibition \tabularnewline
     \hline
    Yellow & Circle & \Centerstack[l]{End of\\ Prohibition\\ (construction)}\tabularnewline
      \hline
       \end{tabular}
       \label{Spanish_TS}
       \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]